# Sql Server 2012 and native client 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, native-client

What is the difference between SQL Server Native client versions 10 and 11? Can I use Native Client 10 with SQL Server 2012 running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Native Client 10

Simply use `Provider=SQLNCLI10` in the connection string

Comment: But what functionality of SQL Server 2012 will be lost using it with Native Client 10? Can I read about it somewhere?